# Locator is not found on robot framework for Click Button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I want to click "Create an account" button by robot framework on RIDE using the followings keywords

1. Click Button id=SubmitCreate
2. Click Button class=btn btn-default button button-medium exclusive
3. Click Button xpath=//*[@id="SubmitCreate"]

Above locator is not found on the console error is displaying.

Website [link](http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account):

```html
http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account
```

Note: same scripts also work on Google Chrome browser. It's not working on firefox browser(version:59.0.3).

Tag details:

```html
<button class="btn btn-default button button-medium exclusive" type="submit" id="SubmitCreate" name="SubmitCreate">
       <span>
        <i class="icon-user left"></i>
        Create an account
       </span>
      </button>
```

Could you please give a solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also use the following robot framework Keyword


Click Button id=SubmitCreate 
Click Button class=btn btn-default button button-medium exclusive 
Click Button xpath=//*[@id="SubmitCreate"] 

Above locator is not found on the console error is displaying.

Comment: Update the question with this information

Comment: @DebanjanB, Updated successfully.

Comment: What exception are you getting in firefox?

Comment: I want to click "Create an account" button by robot framework on RIDE from http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account

Comment: What is your geckodriver version?

Comment: If it works on one browser and not the other, perhaps one is just running faster than the other. Have you tried waiting for the button to be visible and/or clickable before clicking it?

Comment: @Sujit Apart from my answer,  BryanOakley's suggestion looks as a potential solution to your issue

Comment: @ Pradeep hebbar , I want to click "Create an account" button by robot framework on RIDE from http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account on firefox.

Comment: @Todor, geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, Thank you for your reply.I have tried it by Wait Until Element Is Visible keyword and working good for Google chrome and firefox browser is not working.Also found Element 'id=SubmitCreate' not visible after 20 seconds.The code on RIDE:
"
Click Link class=login   
Wait Until Element Is Visible id=SubmitCreate   20s None 
Click Button id=SubmitCreate "
clickable before clicking keyword is not available on the Robot Framework.Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to capture the ID's/xpaths with Selenium IDE. It's a plugin that is available for both Chrome and FireFox and running the same scenario should yield the same locators. It's a way to discover if there is any differences in the structure of the HTML in the different browsers.'

Comment: @A. Kootstra, Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, there are no differences in the structure of the HTML in the different browsers. Same id SubmitCreate is found in Selenium IDE recorder.  More details may be seen from this link:https://www.screencast.com/t/U03SUfwajDkS This is a simple problem, Why this is not working on firefox browser. I also check older browser version 52 and Gecko driver version too.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared you can use the following *Locator Strategy* :

```
Click Button xpath="//button[@class='btn btn-default button button-medium exclusive' and @id='SubmitCreate']/span[contains(.,'Create an account')]"
```

Comment: Message: Given xpath expression ""//button[@class='btn btn-default button button-medium exclusive' and @id='SubmitCreate']/span[contains(.,'Create an account')]"" is invalid: TypeError: The expression cannot be converted to return the specified type.

Comment: Cross check the single/double quotes

Comment: For single quote
SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression 

For Double quotes
TypeError: The expression cannot be converted to return the specified type.

More details on the video link:https://www.screencast.com/t/Kt9ymXpPRsw

Comment: In Robotframework the quotes around a locator's value, after the identifier (`xpath=`), are not needed. They are in fact a part of the value, thus making the xpath invalid (this will be passed to selenium - `"the_xpath"`); they need to be removed.

Comment: @Sujit As Todor mentioned that might be the exact hurdle we are facing which I have mentioned in my previous comment as in _Cross check the single/double quotes_. Perhaps our _xpath_ is flawless.

Comment: @DebanjanB, Thank you, I also Cross check the single/double quotes. Unfortunately, your xpath is not working.Button with locator 'xpath://button[@class='btn btn-default button button-medium exclusive' and @id='SubmitCreate']/span[contains(.,'Create an account')]' not found. More details video link is https://www.screencast.com/t/Rc6CXasVc

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath

```
//button[@class='btn btn-default button button-medium exclusive']//following::span[1]
```

Try this xpath too

```
 //button[@type='submit' and @name='SubmitCreate']
```

Like this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-default button button-medium exclusive']//following::span[1]")).click();
```

Complete code is like this:

// Open browser

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/sankalp.gupta/Desktop/JAVASELN/geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("file:///C:/Sankalp/test.html");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit' and @name='SubmitCreate']")).click();
```

Comment: Try this pass uour URL in get and set path

Comment: I believe problem is in the driver not in the locator because he gave three ways that he tried in which I don't see any problem for the given page.

Comment: After using above xpath error found as Button with locator 'xpath=//button[@class='btn btn-default button button-medium exclusive']//following::span[1]' not found.

Comment: I dont know that xpath works for me, I also add new xpath try that

Comment: @ Rajagopalan Thank you for your suggestion. Could you please inform me which type of driver problem would occur and what is the solution for that case.

Comment: @ iamsankalp89, Thank you, your XPath is working and test cases is Pass. But the browser is not able to click on Create an account button. More details may be seen from the link:https://www.screencast.com/t/uHoSRz5P6UZ

Comment: Okay I will try to look it, Mean while accept as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this **Xpath** , I have verified this from my end and it's working fine :

```
//input[@name='back']/following-sibling::button[@name='SubmitCreate']
```

In **code** you can use it like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:\\Automation\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account");
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='back']/following-sibling::button[@name='SubmitCreate']")));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='back']/following-sibling::button[@name='SubmitCreate']")).click();      
    }
```

Comment: Code on RIDE:
###
Click Link class=login  
Wait Until Element Is Visible xpath://input[@name='back']/following-sibling::button[@name='SubmitCreate'] None None
Click Button xpath://input[@name='back']/following-sibling::button[@name='SubmitCreate']  ## After using your xpath found error.
Element 'xpath://input[@name='back']/following-sibling::button[@name='SubmitCreate']' not visible after 5 seconds.More details link is:https://www.screencast.com/t/uOfsyBes

Answer (score 0):

@Sujit It's not a locator problem. It's browser's version problem. I used FireFox version 56.0 and driver any geckodriver among v0.18.0 to v0.20.1. This configuration is working fine my site.

You can try with this configuration. It can be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your great analysis of FireFox & gecko driver version.